# Cannot programmatically change a textbox after a user has changed it's value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danashurst/36mx3537/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1 -</td>
    <td>
        <input id="1" class="primaryChannel" type="text" value="9">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2 -</td>
    <td>
        <input class="channelValue" type="text" value="-4">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3 -</td>
    <td>
        <input class="channelValue" type="text" value="5">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
        filterInt = function (value) {
        if (/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/.test(value)) return Number(value);
        return 0;
    }

    $('.channelValue').each(function () {
        var elem = $(this);

        // Save current value of element.
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

        // Look for changes in the value.
        elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function (event) {
            // If value has changed...
            if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
                // Calculate the difference between the old and the new value.
                var difference = elem.data('oldVal') - elem.val();

                // Updated stored value.
                elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

                // Remove the difference from the first textbox.                
                $('.primaryChannel').attr("value", filterInt($('.primaryChannel').val()) + difference);

            }
        });
    });
```

When a user changes the numerical value of either textbox 2 or 3, the difference in the change is reflected on textbox 1.

However, when a user changes the value of textbox 1, then changes the values of 2 or 3 - then nothing appears to happen - textbox 1 does not change.

Can anyone suggest a way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: I revised the fiddle based upon Quentin's correct answer: http://jsfiddle.net/danashurst/36mx3537/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.attr('value', someValue)` but the value **attribute** sets the **default** value and not the **current** value.

Set the value **property** instead. Use `.val(someValue)` or `.prop('value', someValue)`.

Comment: +1 Excellent. I had a feeling I was pretty close with what I already had. Thanks so much for this, and the explanation.